# Cookies aren't applying from karate-config.js

Tags: karate

I have faced a problem with setting global cookies from karate-config.js file.
I have two features:

1. login.feature as helpers
2. postItem.feature as test, which is also using cookieKey in path.

In login.feature I get this `cookieKey` like this:

```
* def cookieKey = responseCookies.user_cookie_key.value
```

To make postItem, I need to call login.feature, which contains credentials and `cookieKey` as part of path, to get cookies, which are using for postItem.
If I call login.feature inside postItem.feature in Background section, everything works fine.
But I want to move calling login.feature to karate-config.js because I dont want to put this to each future features.
And what I did in karate-config.js:

```
  var response = karate.call('classpath:/helpers/features/login.feature');
  var cookieKey = response.cookieKey;
  karate.set('cookieKey', cookieKey);
```

I receive `cookieKey` and able to re-use it in my feaure postItem like this:

```
* def cookieKey = karate.get('cookieKey')
```

But problem in the next, cookies from login.feature, which is calling from karate-config.js is not applying for postItem because call is covered in variable, but even without variable, they aren't applying.
Could you help me to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you just need to use `configure cookies`: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#configure

I also think if you use the alternate method signature of `karate.call()` it will work: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#call-vs-read

```
var response = karate.call(true, 'classpath:/helpers/features/login.feature');
```

Comment: Alternate method works perfectly) Tnx a lot)

Comment: It works, but it runs for each feature. And I dont want that before each feature was a new login.
When I try to use 
var response = karate.callSingle(true, 'classpath:/helpers/features/login.feature');
It doesn't work
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: invokeMember (callSingle) on com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioBridge@661c46bc failed due to: no applicable overload found

Comment: @Holgar callSingle is a completely different discussion. if you use that, you need to ensure that cookies are set up manually. so get the result from `callSingle()` and then do a `karate.configure('cookies', someJson)`. if you can't get that to work, just call a re-usable feature. anyway refer: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/headers/headers-single.feature